# Internet explorer not playing nice - Site left aligned and not 100% width

Tags: html, css

My site works perfectly in chrome but now that I have tested it with IE7 and not only is the site left aligned, but the full width (100%) header background no longer extends all the way across and the header and content is left aligned.

Seemingly it is only the footer that works correctly. I dont have a clue why this is, but rather than "hack" it to work, I am sure that there is something I have put wrong in my code.

I cant figure this out though! Here is my code:

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
        <title>Title</title>
        <link href="main2.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<!--[if !IE 7]>
    <style type="text/css">
        #wrap {display:table;height:100%}
    </style>
<![endif]-->
    </head>
    <body>
<div id="wrap">
    <div id="header">
<div id="header_content">                        
    <a href="/"><img src="/static/img/header.jpg" id="logo" alt="coming soon" title="coming soon"></a>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="/posts/list/">Link1</a></li>
                            <li><a href="/posts/create/">Link 2</a></li>
                            <li><a href="/about">Link 3</a></li>
                        </ul>
    </div>
    </div>

    <div id="main">
There are many sticky footer methods to be found in Google. I've tried many of them and they usually fail in some regards. The problem it seems is that some of these methods are old and may have worked in older browsers but they don't in newer browser releases. Because those pages are old, and were heavily linked too in the past, they still rank high in Google. Many webmasters looking for a sticky footer solution end up scratching their heads as they try these same old methods because they are the first ones they end up finding when they search.
    </div>
    </div>

<div id="footer">
    <div id="footer_content">
           &#169; 2012 Company, Inc.
           <ul>
                <li><a href="/contact">Contact</a></li>
                <li><a href="/contact">Terms</a></li>
                <li><a href="/contact">Privacy</a></li>
           </ul>
</div>
    </div> 
</body>
</html>
```

**CSS**

```
* { margin: 0; padding: 0; }
html, body {height: 100%; }
body { min-width:900px; }

/* LAYOUT */
#wrap {min-height: 100%;}
#main { background-color: purple; margin: 0 auto; overflow: auto; padding-bottom: 60px; width: 900px; } 
body:before { content:""; height:100%; float:left; width:0; margin-top:-32767px;/ } /*Opera Fix*/

/* HEADER */
#header { background-color: orange; width: 100%; line-height: 60px; } 
#header_content { position: relative; width: 900px; margin: 0 auto; }
#header ul { list-style: none; position: absolute; top: 0; right: 0; }
#header ul li { float: left; }
#header ul li a { font-weight: bold; text-decoration: none; }
#header ul li a:hover {  }

/* FOOTER */ 
#footer { margin-top: -60px; clear:both; background-color: blue; line-height: 60px; } 
#footer_content { width: 900px; margin: 0 auto; position: relative;}
#footer ul { list-style: none; position: absolute; top: 0px; right: 0; }
#footer ul li { float: left; margin-right: 5px; }
#footer ul li a { font-weight: bold; margin-right: 5px; text-decoration: none; }
#footer ul li a:hover {  }
```

Comment: I dont have a site but I put it here: http://jsfiddle.net/PUqzV/ I dont know if it will render the same through jsfiddle though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Small CSS Change:

```
* { margin: 0; padding: 0; }
html, body {height: 100%; }
body { min-width:900px; }

/* LAYOUT */
#wrap {min-height: 100%;}
#main { background-color: purple; margin: 0 auto; overflow: auto; padding-bottom: 60px;} 
#main .wrap {width: 900px; margin: auto;}
body:before { content:""; height:100%; float:left; width:0; margin-top:-32767px;/ } /*Opera Fix*/

/* HEADER */
#header { background-color: orange; width: 100%; line-height: 60px; margin: auto;} 
#header_content { position: relative; margin: 0 auto; width: 900px; }
#header ul { list-style: none; position: absolute; top: 0; right: 0; }
#header ul li { float: left; }
#header ul li a { font-weight: bold; text-decoration: none; }
#header ul li a:hover {  }

/* FOOTER */ 
#footer { margin-top: -60px; clear:both; background-color: blue; line-height: 60px; } 
#footer_content { width: 900px; margin: 0 auto; position: relative;}
#footer ul { list-style: none; position: absolute; top: 0px; right: 0; }
#footer ul li { float: left; margin-right: 5px; }
#footer ul li a { font-weight: bold; margin-right: 5px; text-decoration: none; }
#footer ul li a:hover {  }
```

#### Fiddle: http://jsbin.com/iyedik/1

Comment: Thank you. This centralises the header and content, but still the header background doesnt extend all the way across like it does in chrome.

Comment: Yeah, I will do it. Gimme some time. Can you?

Comment: Ok. There must be a bug somewhere because I am sure this was working before without any hacks

Comment: @user1738522 Updated. Please check. **No hacks!**

Comment: The trouble is now the center content is 100% width. How to make this sit in the middle at 900px?

Comment: @user1738522 Check, the center content is only `900px` in width. See the link I have given.

Comment: div {
width:900px; margin:0 auto;
}

Comment: I dont want to have to add any more divs because this is working in chrome without them. Your latest code is 100% middle content width on chrome and IE7 (the only browsers I can test on)

Comment: @besluitloos No don't give a general selector.

Comment: @user1738522 Yeah, so is my latest code working as expected in Chrome and IE 7?

Comment: No, I said the center content is 100% width instead of 900px

Comment: @JamesWillson Okay, in that case, remove the `#main .wrap` rule as here: http://jsbin.com/ayivus/1

Comment: What browser are you looking at this in? the purple content is still 100% width...

Comment: Content or Background? I am seeing both in Chrome and IE 7. PS: Do you see a difference in http://jsbin.com/ayivus/1 and http://jsbin.com/iyedik/1?

Comment: Content should be 900px, purple should be 100%. Ah, this one seems to work in chrome. http://jsbin.com/iyedik/1 but not in IE

Comment: @JamesWillson There is a `display: table;` for `#wrap`. Remove that and it works fine in `IE 9`! :) But it actually works well in `IE 7`.

Comment: This breaks the docked footer in IE7 though :(. So although the content is the right width, the footer is no longer docked correctly.